# Is it possible to check the Connected RPC network in MetaMask using JQuery?

Tags: solidity, blockchain, metamask, ethereum-wallet-dapp, jquery

In my DApp, I want to check whether the MetaMask in connected to BSC Minnet RPC network using JQuery. Is it possible to check the Connected RPC network in MetaMask using JQuery?

Thanks a bunch in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

To get the current network connection you could use its [chainId](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/ethereum-provider.html#chain-ids).

```
ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_chainId' })
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is a JavaScript library for DOM manipulation. jQuery is unrelated to MetaMask that interacts with JavaScript.